# Tableau - multiple records that meet IF condition

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api

I would like to multiple values that meet criteria in tableau.

For example:

```
if [order status] = cancelled and [dtime] = express then 39 
else other end (so it counts number of records *39)
```

What I need is to not count the number of records but all unique `order_id`’s so I used:

```
if [order status] = cancelled and [dtime] = express then (countd[order id] * 39)
```

but this does not work.

scenario :
COUNTD(If

[Expedition Type] = "ZEX" and [count bigboxy aj smallboxy] = "BIGBOX" and [Transporter] = "Mall Box"   then  [Order Id] * 260.6

```
 ELSEIF  ([Expedition Type] = "ZEX" and [count bigboxy aj smallboxy] = "BIGBOX" and [Transporter]= "Mall Pick-Up") then [Order Id] * 260.7
 ELSEIF  ([Expedition Type] = "ZEX" and [count bigboxy aj smallboxy] = "BIGBOX" and [Transporter] = "Ulozenka") then  [Order Id] * 260.6
 ELSEIF  ([Expedition Type] = "ZEX" and [count bigboxy aj smallboxy] = "BIGBOX" and [Transporter] = "--empty--" or [Transporter] = "Cash and Carry" or [Transporter] = "Česká pošta"
  or [Transporter] = "DPD" or [Transporter] = "Helicar" or [Transporter] = "Mall doprava" or [Transporter] = "PPL CZ" or [Transporter] = "Speedy Kuryr" or [Transporter] = "TopTrans CZ" or [Transporter] = "WE|DO" 
  or [Transporter] = "Gebrüder Weiss") then [Order Id] * 260.6 END)
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a simple inpunt and outpot as well in order to better explain what your scenario looks like

Comment: Hello Fabio, i have tried Andy's answear, and if works only if I have couple conditions, if I wand to combine, it does not work:COUNTD(If

Answer (score 1):

COUNTD(if [order status] = cancelled and [dtime] = express then [order id] END) * 39

Comment: Hello Andy, thank you very much, problem is that I have multiple combinations and multiple pricing, so it works only for one option

Comment: Can you use AND / OR statements to cover the combinations?